# Android Lollipop - No Peer Certificate

Tags: android, spring, apache, ssl

I am using Godaddy CA for implementing ssl in my tomcat server for android. It working fine for Kitkat(4.4) but it gives No certificate error in Lollipop (5.1) version. I can't figure this out.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:393)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)